# ChildBrowser plugin for cordova 2.0 (android)

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

Hi my old plugin ( Childbrowser ) not working in  cordova 2.0  anyone please help me , how can i upgrade older version to cordova 2.0 (android), or any new version of child browser plugin is available ?.

**UPDATE** 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser/2.0.0

Comment: it think u need to change the calling style of Cordova.exec

Comment: hi i got new version https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser/2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url,'http://google.com');
```

In my project it works and I didn't change my AndroidManifest.

Comment: hi dex thnks for ur comment i got new version https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser/2.0.0